# Help in solving the integral if exist.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I need help to evaluate the integral for a given $z$. In some sense I want to perform Stieltjes transform to a Gaussian. Here, for simplicity assuming zero mean and unit variance Gaussian. Help to perform the integral for any mean and variance would be appreciated.

$$f(x)=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x^2}}{z-x}\,\text{d}x$$

Comment: [Here's the result !](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5Einf+(e%5E(-x%5E2)%2F(z-x))dx) Judging from its complexity, it should be a tough issue calculating it.

Comment: Is there any restriction on $z$?

Comment: @omegadot not on real, where x is defined.

Comment: Might be a duplicate of this https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2295617/269624